# How can I indicate to browser which input field is the username in a signup form?

Tags: html, forms

I'm creating a signup form. It has multiple text fields, the usual input password etc.

When I submit the form, the browsers offer the option to store the user's credentials. But they offer the user's phone as username, probably because it's rendered just before the password field.

I would like to tell the browsers that the correct username credential is a different input field. Is it possible to achieve without changing my signup form order?

Here's my current code:

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h:outputLabel value="Login document *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputMask id="cpf" style="width:100%" required="true"
        mask="9?9999999999" maxlength="11"
        slotChar="" placeholder=""
        readonly="#{method1}"
        value="#{myvalue}">
    </p:inputMask>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8">
    <h:outputLabel value="Full name *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputText id="name" style="width:100%" required="true"
        value="#{othervalue}" />
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8">
    <h:outputLabel value="Email *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputText id="email" style="width:100%"
        value="#{value3}" required="true" />
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h:outputLabel value="Phone *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputMask id="phone" style="width:100%"
    value="#{value4}" mask="(99) 99999-9999"
    required="true" />
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
    <h:outputLabel value="Pwd *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputText type="password" id="senha1" style="width:100%"
        value="#{pwd1}" />
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
    <h:outputLabel value="Repeat pwd *" styleClass="labelFormGrid" />
    <br />
    <p:inputText type="password" id="senha2" style="width:100%"
        value="#{pwd2}" />
</div>
```

Comment: @MrLister I added the code. I would like the first field (cpf) to be the one suggested by the browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try assigning "username" as the automcomplete value of the input tag.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="username" />
```

You can do the same for phone numbers and other types. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values for reference.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but firefox keeps offering me the phone number.

The rendered input tag was: `<input id="form:cpf" name="form:cpf" type="text" autocomplete="username" maxlength="11" placeholder="" style="width:100%" aria-required="true" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputmask ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">`

Comment: ... but chrome did it right! I'm using firefox quantum 69. Don't know why it didn't work, but I'm happy it's doing fine in current chrome.